# Create a dataset for multi-labelled classification

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I have a dataset of the following form:

```
Id  Class

1   a
2   b
2   c
3   c
3   d
3   a
3   e
3   f
4   g
```

And I need to prep this data to perform a multi-label classification
so I use:

```
df.groupby("Id").Class.apply(','.join).reset_index()
```

to get:

```
Id  Class

1   a
2   b,c
3   c,d,e,f
4   g
```

Now the `MultiLabelBinarizer` is unable to process this in its current form because `df.Class` is represented as

`("a", "b,c", "c,d,e,f", "g")`

however, it is supposed to be in the form

`[["a"], ["b","c"], ["c","d","e","f"],["g"]]`

How should I go about it?

Comment: Split by comma "," and then use the MultiLabelBinarizer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) `list`:

```
print (df.groupby("Id").Class.apply(list))
Id
1                [a]
2             [b, c]
3    [c, d, a, e, f]
4                [g]
Name: Class, dtype: object
```

Comment: Works!! Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Supeeer, glad can help!